# Nodejs with Express - Errors when adding mongoDB and mongoose to package.json and running npm install

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Windows 8.1 
Express starting point using Git Bash 
Doing an npm install with python 2.7.10 to avoid 3.4 problems
Is there a problem with the C compiler? 
How do I fix it?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nodeauth",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*"
  }
}
```

The following log is for inclusion of mongodb and mongoose ... I had similar warnings when just including mongodb:

```
$ npm install --python=c:\python27\python
-


> kerberos@0.0.12 install e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp
 (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (nod
e\  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  kerberos.cc
  worker.cc
  security_buffer.cc
  security_buffer_descriptor.cc
  security_context.cc
  security_credentials.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind
semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_buffer.cc) [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mong
odb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind

semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_context.cc) [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mon
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind
semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_buffer_descriptor.cc) [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_m
odules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind
semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules
\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
  base64.c
  kerberos_sspi.c
     Creating library e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\Relea
  se\kerberos.lib and object e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\buil
  d\Release\kerberos.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  kerberos.vcxproj -> e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\Relea
  se\\kerberos.node
npm WARN installMany nopt was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany npmlog was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany request was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany semver was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany tar was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany tar-pack was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany mkdirp was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany rc was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany rimraf was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree


> kerberos@0.0.12 install e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_mod
ules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

\
e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos>if not defin
ed npm_config_node_gyp (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  kerberos.cc
  worker.cc
  security_buffer.cc
  security_buffer_descriptor.cc
  security_context.cc
  security_credentials.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind
semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_buffer.cc) [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mong
oose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind
semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_buffer_descriptor.cc) [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_m
odules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind
semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_context.cc) [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mon
goose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind
semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules
\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
  base64.c
  kerberos_sspi.c
     Creating library e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_module
  s\kerberos\build\Release\kerberos.lib and object e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_mod
  ules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\Release\kerberos.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  kerberos.vcxproj -> e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_module
  s\kerberos\build\Release\\kerberos.node

> bson-ext@0.1.12 install e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext
> (node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build) || (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
"c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node  clean
)

e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
"c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-bui
ld --module=e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release\bson.node --mod
ule_name=bson --module_path=e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release
 --python=c:python27python )  else (node  configure --fallback-to-build --module=e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\
node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release\bson.node --module_name=bson --module_path=e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_m
odules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release --python=c:python27python )

e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
"c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" build --fallback-to-build -
-module=e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release\bson.node --module_
name=bson --module_path=e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release )
else (node  build --fallback-to-build --module=e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bso
n-ext\build\Release\bson.node --module_name=bson --module_path=e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\
node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  bson.cc
..\ext\bson.cc(688): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data [e:\nodejs\_projects
\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\bson.vcxproj]
..\ext\bson.cc(902): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data [e:\nodejs\_projects
\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\bson.vcxproj]
e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\node_modules\nan\nan_new.h(208): warning
 C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int64_t' to 'double', possible loss of data [e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoo
se\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\bson.vcxproj]
          ..\ext\bson.cc(568) : see reference to function template instantiation 'v8::Local NanNew(
  A0)' being compiled
          with
          [
              A0=int64_t
          ]
..\ext\bson.cc(339): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data [e:\nodejs\_proj
ects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\bson.vcxproj]
          ..\ext\bson.cc(153) : while compiling class template member function 'void BSONSerializer::SerializeValue(voi
  d *,const v8::Handle,bool)'
          ..\ext\bson.cc(123) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void BSONSerializer::SerializeValue(v
  oid *,const v8::Handle,bool)' being compiled
          ..\ext\bson.cc(103) : while compiling class template member function 'void BSONSerializer::SerializeDocument(
  const v8::Handle &)'
          ..\ext\bson.cc(879) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void BSONSerializer::SerializeDocumen
  t(const v8::Handle &)' being compiled
          ..\ext\bson.cc(878) : see reference to class template instantiation 'BSONSerializer' being compiled
  win_delay_load_hook.c
     Creating library e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release\bson
  .lib and object e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release\bson.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  bson.vcxproj -> e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\Release\\bson.no
  de
cookie-parser@1.3.5 node_modules\cookie-parser
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
└── cookie@0.1.3

debug@2.2.0 node_modules\debug
└── ms@0.7.1

serve-favicon@2.3.0 node_modules\serve-favicon
├── ms@0.7.1
├── etag@1.7.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
└── fresh@0.3.0

morgan@1.6.1 node_modules\morgan
├── basic-auth@1.0.3
├── on-headers@1.0.0
├── depd@1.0.1
└── on-finished@2.3.0 (ee-first@1.1.1)

body-parser@1.13.3 node_modules\body-parser
├── bytes@2.1.0
├── content-type@1.0.1
├── depd@1.0.1
├── on-finished@2.3.0 (ee-first@1.1.1)
├── qs@4.0.0
├── raw-body@2.1.2 (unpipe@1.0.0)
├── iconv-lite@0.4.11
├── http-errors@1.3.1 (inherits@2.0.1, statuses@1.2.1)
└── type-is@1.6.6 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.4)

express@4.13.3 node_modules\express
├── escape-html@1.0.2
├── merge-descriptors@1.0.0
├── cookie@0.1.3
├── array-flatten@1.1.1
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├── fresh@0.3.0
├── methods@1.1.1
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── vary@1.0.1
├── etag@1.7.0
├── content-type@1.0.1
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── serve-static@1.10.0
├── content-disposition@0.5.0
├── depd@1.0.1
├── on-finished@2.3.0 (ee-first@1.1.1)
├── finalhandler@0.4.0 (unpipe@1.0.0)
├── qs@4.0.0
├── proxy-addr@1.0.8 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@1.0.1)
├── send@0.13.0 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.7.1, statuses@1.2.1, mime@1.3.4, http-errors@1.3.1)
├── type-is@1.6.6 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.4)
└── accepts@1.2.12 (negotiator@0.5.3, mime-types@2.1.4)

jade@1.11.0 node_modules\jade
├── character-parser@1.2.1
├── void-elements@2.0.1
├── commander@2.6.0
├── jstransformer@0.0.2 (is-promise@2.0.0, promise@6.1.0)
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── constantinople@3.0.2 (acorn@2.2.0)
├── with@4.0.3 (acorn@1.2.2, acorn-globals@1.0.5)
├── uglify-js@2.4.24 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, yargs@3.5.4, source-map@0.1.34)
├── clean-css@3.3.9 (commander@2.8.1, source-map@0.4.4)
└── transformers@2.1.0 (promise@2.0.0, css@1.0.8, uglify-js@2.2.5)

mongodb@2.0.41 node_modules\mongodb
├── es6-promise@2.1.1
├── readable-stream@1.0.31 (inherits@2.0.1, isarray@0.0.1, string_decoder@0.10.31, core-util-is@1.0.1)
└── mongodb-core@1.2.10 (bson@0.4.11, kerberos@0.0.12)

mongoose@4.1.2 node_modules\mongoose
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── muri@1.0.0
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── async@0.9.0
├── ms@0.1.0
├── mquery@1.6.1 (bluebird@2.9.26)
├── mongodb@2.0.40 (readable-stream@1.0.31, es6-promise@2.1.1, mongodb-core@1.2.9)
└── bson@0.3.2 (bson-ext@0.1.12)

James@13JY1W1 /E/nodejs/_projects/nodeauth
$ npm start

> nodeauth@0.0.0 start e:\nodejs\_projects\nodeauth
> node ./bin/www
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no error here, the modules installed successfully. The various compiler-related messages are merely warnings, but the compilation was a success.